# session to show message and back button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

i have 3 jsp's :-

1. a.jsp
2. b.jsp
3. c.jsp

From a.jsp i am going to b.jsp to show some result. And when the user update one of the record i call c.jsp which actually update it. So after updation it forward to a.jsp with a message saying "Successfully Updated"  . And i set this message in session . And in a.jsp after showing this message. i invalidate the session.

The problem is , when i press the browser back button it still show the message. 
How can i solve this.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Could you share some source code? However I suspect you're putting java code in a jsp which is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Maybe [this][1] will help...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785682/preventing-user-to-got-back-after-logout-in-jsf

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest few steps to do that...

As you click on back button browser will get the page from cache... so set the JSP page `Expires` date to some previous day/time to get it from server(origin) instead of cache. This can be done by writing a Custom tag and in that tad set `Expires` header on `HttpServletRequest` object and adding that tag to JSP page is enough.

To invalidate the page and redirect to a.jsp when there is no valid session, write a `Filter` to  that job.

Tag can be written like this

```
public class ExpiryTag extends SimpleTagSupport{

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {

        PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext(); 
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) pageContext.getResponse();
        response.addHeader("Expires", instance.getTime().toString());

    }

}
```

Map tag in tld file like this

```
<tag>
            <name>expired</name>
            <tag-class>com.analysis.mvc.tags.ExpiryTag</tag-class>
            <body-content>empty</body-content>
        </tag>
```

Then use the tag in JSP like this

```
<prefix:expired/>
```

For session handling you can go through [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/http-session-handling-tutorial-using-servlet-filters-session-error-filter-servlet-filter.html) for basic understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If a.jsp, b.jsp and c.jsp are a part single process, try putting them on single page (say abc.jsp). Now using some attributes show contents of either a.jsp/b.jsp/c.jsp, something similar to a wizard.